# JavaScript App Architecture: Referencing Object Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, architecture

I have an object called `App` which holds all relevant parts of my backbone application.

#### The problem: when I call objects in App from within other objects in App they are undefined.

I think this is happening because they are being called form within the objects in App before the App object it's self is defined.

#### How can define app before the objects within it call other objects in App?

An example of my App object, where the `App.templates.restaurant` object is being called within the `Restaurant` view and returns undefined:

```
var App = {
      ...

      templates: {
        restaurant: "#RestaurantModel__template",
        menu: "#MenuItemsModel__template"
      },
      
      ...
      
      Views: {
        Restaurant: Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName:  "li",
            template: Handlebars.compile($(App.templates.restaurant).html()),
            ...
           )},

        ...

        }),
      
      ...
}
```

Comment: Isnt there some typo ? can you check what is in App object in debug console on Views function beginning ? From this small piece it seems all correct. And object IS created before you read from it (As I assume you call App.Views after object definition)

Comment: @SergeS I cant evaluate it in the debug console because the error happens when App is defined. This is the error message it throws: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'templates' of undefined`

Comment: My mistake, I had read wrong your code

Comment: @jOshT inside the function `this` refers to the backbone view. I cant use self because it's not defined yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slove it by defining empty object as App , so the processor knows what it is :

```
var App = {};

App.Templates = { ... }

App.Views = { ... }
```

Second solution is to split it into data part and function part (For example by creating init function which will create Views sub.)

```
var App = {
    Templates : { ... },
    init : function() {
        App.Views = { ... }
    }
}
```

Problem is caused because processor firstly creates object (And executes all functions) and only then it will assign it to a variable. You can play around with other constructs.

Comment: great thinking with the `init` method. it lets me keep my desired structure and please the processor, +1. Although, I think the first method you mentioned is cleaner and a better practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = 42;
x = { y : x }
```

The order in which the code is executed is the following:

1. an object is created
2. the y property is added to it with the value of x (42)
3. the object is assigned to the x variable.

A simple and obvious fix is to define the `App` object first and then the properties:

```
var App = {};
App.templates = { /* ... */ }
App.Views = { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: great explanation. it made easy for me to understand what's going on +1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about creating this using a constructor function?

```
function App() {
    this.templates = {
        restaurant: "#RestaurantModel__template",
        menu: "#MenuItemsModel__template"
    };

    var that = this;
    this.views = {
        Restaurant : Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName:  "li",
            template: Handlebars.compile($(that.templates.restaurant).html()),
        ...
       )},
    }
}
```

var App = new App();